# Should xccy basis be added before bootstrapping (to swap curve) or after bootstrapping (to zero curve)?

Tags: bootstrapping, cross-currency-basis

I am trying to bootstrap a GBP zero curve off of a GBP swap (par) curve inclusive of xccy basis (vs USD). Say I have my two curves (swap and basis) - would I sum these and then bootstrap to get zeros, or bootstrap just the swap curve first and then add the basis component to the gbp zero curve? TIA

Comment: The swap curve is a curve. The swap curve + xccy basis is also a curve. But the xccy basis is just a collection of quotes, not a curve.

Comment: Are you trying to get an estimation curve against a collateral currency (so GBP forward rates collateralised in USD?) or an implied yield curve to price FX swaps and discount USD collateralised GBP cash flows? Purpose of the curve drives its construction.

Comment: thanks all for the responses. @river_rat my aim is the latter - I have a fixed fixed cross currency swap (gbp usd) and am trying to construct an appropriate curve to discount the GBP cashflows

Comment: In general, it's not a good idea to interpolate any spread without considering the shape of the curve that it's a spread over.